# can´t manage timeouts in for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some kind of Simon game in javascript. I have already made a table, and a function that changes any cell by its id to another id, so it's color changes for 300 miliseconds. This is the code:

```
var seleccionarcelda = function(object){
  var id=object.id;
  object.id="selected";
  setTimeout(function(){object.id=id;},300);
}
```

Then, for a sequence as large as I want it to, it should light a random cell, and then another cell, in a for loop

```
var secuencia = function(numero){
  for(j=0; j<numero; j++){
      var cel="t"+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
      console.log(cel);
      seleccionarcelda(document.getElementById(cel));
  }
}
```

The problem is that it kind of works, but selects all cells at once, and not in order as it should do. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the loop index into the function and use that as a multiplier of the delay time.

Something like:

```
var seleccionarcelda = function(object, index){
  // increment delay timer
  var delay = (index + 1) * 300;

  var id=object.id;
  object.id="selected";
  setTimeout(function(){object.id=id;}, delay );// use variable for timer delay
}

var secuencia = function(numero){
  for(j=0; j<numero; j++){
      var cel="t"+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
      console.log(cel);
      // pass j to function
      seleccionarcelda(document.getElementById(cel), j);
  }
}
```

What is happening now is the loop completes in milliseconds and therefore all the `setTimeout` start at basically the same time

Comment: It doesn't work because all of the cells turn off, and after that, they turn un in order. I want each of them to turn on and off,one by one

Comment: Not enough shown to help resolve that or fully understand what is needed. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: My guess is you need another setTimeout inside the first with a hard coded 300 delay to reset each one